# Extracting XML nodes into a dataframe when child nodes vary

Tags: r, xml, dataframe, xpath, xml-parsing

I am building a code in R to extract grant data from IRS990PF files in XML format. I have built the following code that works well to build a dataframe for a file with only US grantees. However, the code does not work when there are foreign grantees, because the names of the child nodes are not the same - resulting in lists of different sizes.

My example XML file was this one, for Mondelez International Foundation: https://projects.propublica.org/nonprofits/download-xml?object_id=202043219349103104

And here is my R code:

```r
grant_test <- XML::xmlParse(paste0(getwd(),"/xml_all/Mondelez-2019.xml")) %>%
  XML::xmlToList()

grants_df <- grant_test[["ReturnData"]][["IRS990PF"]][["SupplementaryInformationGrp"]] %>%    
  lapply(function(x) unlist(x)) %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  ## Choose the values to keep
  dplyr::filter(row.names(.) %in% c("RecipientBusinessName.BusinessNameLine1Txt","RecipientFoundationStatusTxt", "GrantOrContributionPurposeTxt","Amt")) %>%
  dplyr::select(-OnlyContriToPreselectedInd, -TotalGrantOrContriPdDurYrAmt,- TotalGrantOrContriApprvFutAmt) %>% 
  ## Transpose dataframe
  tibble::rownames_to_column(var="rowname") %>%
  data.table::transpose(make.names="rowname")
```

It works well and gives me a dataframe where each row is a grant, and there are 4 columns with the grantee name, grantee status, project description, and amount.

The problem is that when I apply this same code to a different XML including grantees outside the US (such as this one: https://projects.propublica.org/nonprofits/download-xml?object_id=202033179349101943) I get this error at the third line ("as.data.frame"):

> Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE,
> check.names = TRUE,  :    arguments imply differing number of rows: 9,
> 8, 7, 10, 1

I know that this error is caused by the fact that grants to international grantees do not have the same child nodes as domestic grants. A US grantee will always look like this:

```
<GrantOrContributionPdDurYrGrp>
  <RecipientBusinessName>
    <BusinessNameLine1Txt>IMMUNARTES LLC</BusinessNameLine1Txt>
  </RecipientBusinessName>
  <RecipientUSAddress>
    <AddressLine1Txt>1463 E 53RD STREET FL 2</AddressLine1Txt>
    <CityNm>CHICAGO</CityNm>
    <StateAbbreviationCd>IL</StateAbbreviationCd>
    <ZIPCd>60615</ZIPCd>
  </RecipientUSAddress>
  <RecipientFoundationStatusTxt>NC: US NON-EXEMPT</RecipientFoundationStatusTxt>
  <GrantOrContributionPurposeTxt>PNEUMONIA</GrantOrContributionPurposeTxt>
  <Amt>198000</Amt>
<GrantOrContributionPdDurYrGrp>
```

Whereas the entry for an international grantee generally looks like the example below (different name for the address node, additional child node for country code), but can also have varying child nodes under "RecipientForeignAddress" (e.g. some lack a province/state number).

```
<GrantOrContributionPdDurYrGrp>
  <RecipientBusinessName>
    <BusinessNameLine1Txt>IMMUNIMED INC</BusinessNameLine1Txt>
  </RecipientBusinessName>
  <RecipientForeignAddress>
    <AddressLine1Txt>62 SCURFIELD BLVD</AddressLine1Txt>
    <CityNm>WINNIPEG</CityNm>
    <ProvinceOrStateNm>MB</ProvinceOrStateNm>
    <CountryCd>CA</CountryCd>
    <ForeignPostalCd>R3Y1M5</ForeignPostalCd>
  </RecipientForeignAddress>
  <RecipientFoundationStatusTxt>NC: FOREIGN NON-EXEM</RecipientFoundationStatusTxt>
  <GrantOrContributionPurposeTxt>DISCOVERY AND TRANSLATIONAL SCIENCES</GrantOrContributionPurposeTxt>
  <Amt>50000</Amt>
<GrantOrContributionPdDurYrGrp>
```

So, my question is: how can I re-design my code to account for the differences of list lengths between different instances of "GrantOrContributionPdDurYrGrp" ? I don't need the addresses in my dataframe, but I would like to keep the country code for international grantees and add United States to that variable for the domestic grantees.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please note that those links will not last too long, and as of now, those are already expired.  Perhaps craft a minimal yet valid XML and include it in your question so we'd have something to test against? Complete and self-contained questions are also much more valuable for others with similar problems. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you! I fixed the links, they should work now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one possible approach with `xml2`.
We'll first create a `xml_nodeset`, one node per grant, and turn it into a regular nested list; when iterating over grants in the list, we'll extract specific items and for non-existing items end up having `NA` values, resulting named list can then be converted into data.frame / tibble.

One of the assumptions here is that missing `.//RecipientForeignAddress/CountryCd` node automatically means existing and valid `RecipientUSAddress`, so once the list is turned into a tibble with `bind_rows()`, all `NA` values in `CountryCd` column are considered as non-foreign record indicators and `CountryCd` for those is set to `US`

```r
library(xml2)

grant_test_int  <- read_xml("https://projects.propublica.org/nonprofits/download-xml?object_id=202033179349101943")
xml_ns_strip(grant_test_int)

grants_df <- xml_find_all(grant_test_int, "/Return/ReturnData/IRS990PF/SupplementaryInformationGrp/GrantOrContributionPdDurYrGrp") |>
  as_list() |>
  lapply(\(grant_node) list(
    BusinessName     = grant_node$RecipientBusinessName$BusinessNameLine1Txt[[1]],
    FoundationStatus = grant_node$RecipientFoundationStatusTxt[[1]],
    Purpose          = grant_node$GrantOrContributionPurposeTxt[[1]],
    Amt              = as.numeric(grant_node$Amt[[1]]),
    CountryCd        = grant_node$RecipientForeignAddress$CountryCd[[1]]
    )) |> 
  dplyr::bind_rows() |>
  tidyr::replace_na(list(CountryCd = "US"))
grants_df
#> # A tibble: 3,712 × 5
#>    BusinessName                        FoundationStatus Purpose    Amt CountryCd
#>    <chr>                               <chr>            <chr>    <dbl> <chr>    
#>  1 1 FOR THE PLANET INC                PC: 509(A)(1)    GLOBAL… 5.07e4 US       
#>  2 1000 DAYS                           PC: 509(A)(1)    NUTRIT… 1   e6 US       
#>  3 100 BLACK MEN OF AMERICA INC        PC: 509(A)(2)    GLOBAL… 4   e5 US       
#>  4 2164 INC                            PC: 509(A)(2)    GLOBAL… 5   e4 US       
#>  5 4POINT0 SCHOOLS                     PC: 509(A)(1)    K-12 E… 1   e6 US       
#>  6 501 COMMONS                         PC: 509(A)(1)    PACIFI… 3   e5 US       
#>  7 A-ALPHA BIO INC                     NC: US NON-EXEM… SUPPOR… 6.87e4 US       
#>  8 AARON DIAMOND AIDS RESEARCH CENTER… PC: 509(A)(1)    HIV     7.55e5 US       
#>  9 ABT ASSOCIATES INC                  NC: US NON-EXEM… FAMILY… 1.41e6 US       
#> 10 ACADEMISCH MEDISCH CENTRUM          GOV: FOREIGN GO… HIV     1.53e6 NL       
#> # ℹ 3,702 more rows
```

The first attempt - https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/77332323/1 - tried to avoid `xml2::to_list()` and extracted just specific nodes from XML tree by passing grant nodes repeatedly through `xml2::xml_find_first()`; it was about 20x slower.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you!